# Is GCC 4.4.1 buggy by not accepting an injected-class-name in a ctor-initializer?

Tags: c++, gcc

GCC 4.4.1 is refusing to find my *injected-class-name* within a *ctor-initializer*:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    Base(int x) {}
};

struct Derived : Base<int>
{
    Derived() : Base(2) {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

> ```
> test2.cpp: In constructor "Derived::Derived()":
> test2.cpp:9: error: class "Derived" does not have any field named "Base"
> test2.cpp:9: error: no matching function for call to "Base<int>::Base()"
> test2.cpp:4: note: candidates are: Base<T>::Base(int) [with T = int]
> test2.cpp:3: note:                 Base<int>::Base(const Base<int>&)
> ```

GCC 4.8 [compiles it just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc45ff4f1629604f), though.

I'm sure this is supposed to work, and I can't find any standard wording that disagrees with me.

**This a GCC 4.4.1 bug, right?**

<sup>(I did scour GCC Bugzilla but nothing relevant popped out at me.)</sup>

Comment: Can you use `Base` outside of the constructor? Maybe GCC 4.4 thinks `Base` is a dependant name.

Comment: Not sure, but looks somewhat similar to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45515

Comment: @Simple: Nope - even this fails: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23d997547aa80bab. So I suppose I could have abstracted out the _ctor-initializer_ too!

Comment: @BoBTFish: That looks like the one.

Comment: @Simple: `Derived` is not a template, `Base` cannot be dependent on any template argument

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm aware, that's why it's a bug. GCC might think it is. You could test `typename Derived::Base` to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Just tried to compile it with a few: GCC 4.4.0 : failed
GCC 4.4.1 : failed
GCC 4.4.2 : failed
GCC 4.4.3 : failed
GCC 4.4.4 : failed
GCC 4.4.5 : failed
GCC 4.4.6 : failed
GCC 4.4.7 : failed
GCC 4.5.0 : success
GCC 4.5.1 : success
GCC 4.5.2 : success
GCC 4.5.3 : success
GCC 4.5.4 : success
GCC 4.6.0 : success
GCC 4.6.1 : success
GCC 4.6.2 : success
GCC 4.6.3 : success
GCC 4.7.0 : success
GCC 4.7.1 : success
GCC 4.7.2 : success
GCC 4.7.3 : success
GCC 4.8.0 : success
GCC 4.8.1 : success
GCC 4.8.2 : success

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Ahhhhh where were you an hour ago when I wanted to ask you to do that :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yeah, it *is* a bug.**

I can reproduce it even more simply without the *ctor-initialiser*:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : Base<int>
{
    Base* ptr;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}

/**
 * in GCC 4.4.1:
 * 
 * error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of "Base" with no type
 */
```

And:

> `[C++11: 14.6.1/4]:` A lookup that finds an *injected-class-name* (10.2) can result in an ambiguity in certain cases (for example, if it is found in more than one base class). If all of the injected-class-names that are found refer to specializations of the same class template, and if the name is used as a *template-name*, the reference refers to the class template itself and not a specialization thereof, and is not ambiguous. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct Base { };
> template <class T> struct Derived: Base<int>, Base<char> {
>    typename Derived::Base b;            // error: ambiguous
>    typename Derived::Base<double> d;    // OK
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Notice that the near-equivalent of my unambiguous usage is "OK". Alright, so `Derived` is a class template here and not in my example, so it's not *quite* the same example. But I'm satisfied now that the entirety of 14.6.1 makes my code legal.

Turns out it had been raised as [GCC bug 45515](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45515)<sup>†</sup>, but since it had been fixed on *head* at the time there are very few details on it.

<sup><sup>†</sup> Thanks [BoBTFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171191/bobtfish)!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use `: Base<int>(2) {}`

*(edit: sorry, I just took away the CRTP element as it's not needed to reproduce)*

Comment: Is this a "yes" or a "no"?

Comment: Sure, that fixes it. But it does not answer the question!

Comment: I would think that it is rather 4.8 bug - I think that without the template argument the code is invalid. Don't have the standard text handy to confirm it though...

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: The _injected-class-name_ is supposed to be within the scope of the whole type and its derived types. `[C++11: 14.6.1/3]` gives an example, albeit not _quite_ this one.

Comment: I'd vote for 4.8 bug (don't have the standard handy either), what would `Base` refer to in the case of `struct Derived : Base<int>, Base<double>`?

Comment: @Erbureth it's not a 4.8 bug. In that case it's an ambiguity. You could even derive from `std::vector<int>` if you wanted and use `vector` as a name.

Comment: @Erbureth copies of draft standard can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Comment: @Erbureth: `[C++11: 14.6.1/4]:` _A lookup that finds an injected-class-name (10.2) can result in an ambiguity in certain cases (for example, if it is found in more than one base class). If all of the injected-class-names that are found refer to specializations
of the same class template, and if the name is used as a template-name, the reference refers to the class
template itself and not a specialization thereof, and is not ambiguous._

Comment: @Erbureth: In fact, the example in this paragraph is _precisely_ the example you give! And it says that it should be valid as long as there's no ambiguity. That proves that it's a GCC 4.4.1 bug as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That decides it then.

Comment: @Erbureth: Thanks for your prodding. :) I didn't spot that example before you spoke up.

Comment: The example is not the same, since Derived is a template in the standard. The whole discussion in 14.6.1 (in my draft it is 14.7.1) is about class templates. In the code above struct Derived is not a template, so 14.6.1 is not relevant. Can anyone point to a text in the standard which explains 4.8 behaviour?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: It doesn't really work that way. There's no wording to state that this factor matters. The entirety of 14.6.1 makes my code legal and I'm sure of it now!

Comment: The standard says "The injected-class-name of a class template or class template specialization can be used either with or without
a template-argument-list wherever it is in scope." In your case Derived is not a class template or class template specialization, so it is really not relevant.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: The _injected-class-name_ in this example is that of `Base`, which is absolutely a class template.